# Looking for an app to update/sync all services on demand

Tags: sync, twitter

**The problem**: When I goto the toilet at work, there is no signal at all, so my  smart phone isn't particularly useful at the times it should be.

**The solution**: Run an app via a button/shortcut/widget that forces Twitter, Facebook, Gmail, Google+ etc to update *before* I go so I have some reading material.

Does such an app exist?

Comment: You want to update it after your done with your toilet business? Din't quite understand when you want this button!

Comment: Sorry, meant before I go; clarified that now.

Comment: i can't think of anything but tweetcaster, one app jus open it once and it updates your fb and twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Accounts and sync -> Sync All (bottom left). This will sync every app that register there, like Facebook, Twitter, Gmail and Google+, but not all the apps.

Comment: Some shortcut needed!